# Why did my regex not give the desired result

Tags: regex

I have a string from which I need to extract specific url that consists of an image extension and the following regex:

```
ITEMIMAGEURL\d+=(http://.*?)(,|$|\n)
```

and the string that I've to extract from is:

```
ITEMIMAGEURL0 = http://images.example.com/xyz/l/dasda/test-image-6af8af8afa9.jpg,
ITEMIMAGEURL1 = http://images.example.com/xyz/l/dasda/test-image-,
ITEMIMAGEURL2 = http://images.example.com/abc/as/test/test-image-abrd23lg9.jpg
```

My regex works fine but I want to extract only the url with `.jpg|.gif` or any other image extension so I've tried

```
ITEMIMAGEURL\d+=(http://.*?(?(?=.[a-zA-Z]{3,4})))(,|$|\n)
```

But it didn't work as expected

My expected result is

```
http://images.example.com/xyz/l/dasda/test-image-6af8af8afa9.jpg
http://images.example.com/abc/as/test/test-image-abrd23lg9.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract image URLs:

```
ITEMIMAGEURL\d+=(http://[^,\s]+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zm9kay/1)

Your image URL is captured in group #1. This assumes your URL doesn't contain comma character.

If comma is allowed in image URLs then use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
ITEMIMAGEURL\d+=(http://(?:(?!,ITEMIMAGEURL\d).)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png))
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Zm9kay/2)

Comment: Awesome this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
ITEMIMAGEURL\d+=(http:\/(?:\/[\w\.-]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png),?\s?)?
```

I think you know basics of RegExp. So one one: `(?:\/[\w\.-]+)` this is a pattern of valid url path. This is not only valid one, you could choose any you like, e.g. `(?:\/[^\s,]+)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SR1icX/1)